# How to access Pytorch Tensor Data using its memory adress?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm creating a pytorch tensor with

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(100,100,device='cuda')
adr = x.data_ptr() #gives address to first element of x, e.g. 30119297024
```

is there a way to access the tensordata when only knowing
`adr` and do something like

```
y = get_tensor_from_address(adr)
```

Where `y` and `x` refer to the same tensor?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I don't think this is a good (*safe*) idea...

Comment: I have multiple independent microservices running on the same machine, that receive an image via http-request, process the image on the gpu and send it back. I'd like to find a way to do this without sending the image directly, because currently I have to transfer the imagedata between cpu and gpu memory for each processing step

Comment: *way to do this without sending the image directly* if the data buffer doesn't live on the destination device, you can't just access it using its data pointer from the source device. I'm not sure to follow you here.

Comment: No, the data should always live on the same device. I just want different microservices to be able to access it, without having to switch devices.

Comment: I'd do that to study the behavior of bfloat16 on binary level to compare it with float32. Apparently, Swift doesn't support bfloat16, nor C++ < 23. If you don't have the most recent compiler or CUDA installed / available, it's a fun easy way to get fully compliant implementation.

Comment: Where you able to answer your question? I'm interested in the same.